# Create a Drop-down of account:type field without using controller?

Tags: visualforce

I was wondering whether it's possible to define a drop-down list in a vf page without populating its values from a controller?

Comment: Hi @Saumya Gaikwad, prior to asking did you do some research on the web? if yes, can you link any docs, if no, please do so. Additionally, what is your use case, why wouldn't you want to use a controller?  thanks!

Comment: Hi @glls, There is no such requirement of not using the controller. i already did my research on this and came out with all solutions using controllers(extensions). I wanted to know whether we can create drop-downs without using controller.

Comment: Did you try to solve it thru a Javascript?

Comment: ok, next time please make sure you include more details in your post. you want to let others know you did some effort into researching prior to posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You could use the [Ajax Toolkit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_introducing.htm), however, an apex controller is always preferred, it is even mentioned in the page linked below:

> An easier way to create this page is by using an Apex controller.
> However, the sample is intended to show basic functionality with the
> AJAX Toolkit that contains API calls and processes Salesforce data.

Here is a [sample VF page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_vf_sample.htm) using the Ajax Toolkit from which you can fetch object records, for Example:

> sforce.connection.query(
> "Select Id, Name, Industry From Account order by Industry",
> callback);

You can see that you end up doing a SOQL to fetch records for a given Object.

You can then use the returned records to populate a dropdown. You will see from the documentation that it comes up to more than just 1 line of code.

Comment: Consider there is a picklist in Account standard object (say Type), even than i have to append this code?

Comment: yes. as far as I am concerned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`apex:selectList`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectList.htm), with nested [`apex:selectOption`'s](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectOption.htm) to define a drop-down list on a visualforce page with requiring data from a controller.

When you see a `selectList`, generally, it's in this form, with a `List<SelectOption>` being defined in the controller:

```
<apex:selectList value="{!countries}" multiselect="true">
     <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

But, you can nest `selectOption` elements under a `selectList`, creating a visualforce list without needing data. You can still use a controller for the `value` attribute, but even that isn't required.

```
<apex:selectList id="chooseColor" value="{!string}" size="1">
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="red" itemLabel="Red"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="white" itemLabel="White"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="blue" itemLabel="Blue"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

---

For your specific example, if you are going to use a drop-down to mirror a field on an object, you're likely better off using a `apex:inputField` and a standard controller, with an extension for whatever functionality you are adding.